# JQuery bind/unbind mousewheel event

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am trying to enable and disable scrolling on my page

I have this function :

```
function scroll_toggle(key){
    if (key) {
        $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
            $('body').on({
                'mousewheel': function(e) {
                    console.log("binded");
                    $("html body").scrollTop(0);
                    if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }});
        });
    } else {
        $(window).unbind('scroll');
         $('body').on({
                'mousewheel': function(e) {
                    console.log("unbinded");
                    return true;

                }});
    }
}
```

When I call this function for the first time with true as parameter, the mousewheel don't work, and a I have "binded" in my console.

But when I call the function with false, the mousewheel still don't work and i have "binded" and "unbinded" alternatively.

What is wrong in my code?

Thanks for your time

Comment: have you looked at mousewheel.js?  It has on() and off() functions.

Comment: I dont have mousewheel.js, i thought mousewheel was the name of the event

Comment: `scroll` is the event used by jquery.  mousewheel is a plugin found here:  https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/

Comment: I looked into this plugin, and in found a completly other solution to my problem.
I had a class to my div "scroll" & "noscroll" and the function now add one and remove the other depending on the parameters.

Thanks a lot for the clue ;)

Comment: is your problem resolved or still you need to this to be fixed

Comment: as I said, i found a solution that fix my problem, but with an entirely different approach.